# Cannot read property 'ENVIRONMENT' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack

I'm deploying a react app on `heroku` on `staging` mode. Since heroku by defaults executes `build` and `start` script, it won't pass `env.ENVIRONMENT=staging`. Locally I do `npm run build:stag` and it works.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --env.ENVIRONMENT=development --mode development",
    "start:stag": "NODE_ENV=staging node -r dotenv/config server.js",
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config server.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "build:stag": "webpack --env.ENVIRONMENT=staging --mode production"
}
```

I'm not sure how can make `start:stag` run on `heroku` or `netlify`.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

module.exports = env => {
  // Get the root path
  const currentPath = path.join(__dirname);

  // Create the fallback path (the production .env)
  const currEnv = env.ENVIRONMENT;
  const basePath = currentPath + "/.env";
  const envPath = basePath + "." + currEnv;
  const finalPath = fs.existsSync(envPath) ? envPath : basePath;

  // Set the path parameter in the dotenv config
  const fileEnv = dotenv.config({ path: finalPath }).parsed;

  // reduce it to a nice object, the same as before (but with the variables from the file)
  const envKeys = Object.keys(fileEnv).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(fileEnv[next]);
    return prev;
  }, {});
  return {
    // other things........
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom environment variables via `app.json` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#env

Comment: How can use `.env` file for the same?

Comment: You shouldn't commit `.env` files and Heroku doesn't accept them. You'd have to load it in the code but there is no possibility for that since `npm build` is called first.
You set environment variables directly through the `heroku` cli or through `app.json` (and the resulting web page with Heroku Button (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button) if used).

Comment: How to add app.json for different envs?

Comment: "environments": {
    "test": {
      "env": {
        "SECRET_TOKEN": "test-secret"
      }
    }
  }
only `test` and `review` are supported. What about prod?

Comment: Here are a few exampels from my projects: [Project A](https://github.com/NNTin/Red-kun/blob/master/app.json), [Project B](https://github.com/NNTin/shell-kun/blob/master/app.json) and [Project C](https://github.com/NNTin/discord-twitter-bot/blob/master/app.json)

Comment: There is no segregation based on env in the example projects.

Comment: `app.json` is only used on Heroku. It is production.

Comment: That is great, what if want to deploy as staging?

Comment: [This is a Heroku Deploy button](https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?button-url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FNNTin%2Fdiscord-twitter-bot&template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FNNTin%2Fdiscord-twitter-bot). You can modify the environment variables prior to deployment. You can also modify the environment post deployment in your App settings.